# filtering arrays using array contents

Tags: swift

i want to print the name in world array which belong to continent: "europe"

```
    struct countries{
    let name: String
    let continent: String
}

var world: [countries] = [
    countries(name:"japan", continent: "asia"),
    countries(name:"france", continent: "europe"),
    countries(name:"italy", continent: "europe"),
    countries(name:"egypt", continent: "africa")
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i use array.filter to filter a class object based on a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647994/how-do-i-use-array-filter-to-filter-a-class-object-based-on-a-property)

Comment: Naming tips, start your class and struct names with an upper case letter and since each instance contains one country use singulars not plural in the name so countries -> Country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
world.filter { $0.continent == "europe" }.forEach { print($0.name) }
```

If you want an array of Names:

```
world.filter { $0.continent == "europe" }.map { $0.name }
```

Comment: what if i wanted  the name to be returned as a string instead of printing it.

Comment: Updated the Answer :)

Comment: is it possible to update the world array to include only the filtered items or create a new array of the same type with the filtered items

Comment: `let array = world.filter { ... }` or: `world = world.filter { ... }`